# IAP Android problems trying to upgrade subscription with getBuyIntentExtraParams not returning BUY_INTENT key

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

On android, I am trying to figure out how to upgrade my subscription in app purchasing. So pretend I have 3 subscription type tier 1, 2 and 3. I purchase my first subscription tier 1 with this method getBuyIntent and then this method returns a bundle with a RESPONSE_CODE key and a BUY_INTENT key.

Then with that bundle I do a bundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT"); which returns a PendingIntent and everything is good.

But when I want to upgrade from tier 1 to tier 2 I need to use this method getBuyIntentExtraParams according to this https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getBuyIntent

When I use getBuyIntentExtraParams, the bundle that is returned does not contain a BUY_INTENT key but it returns INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST, INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST and a INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST key.

INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST is = ["product.id.name.tier1"]

So it almost seems like getBuyIntentExtraParams is returning what you have already bought.. Which is very similar to the method getPurchases().

I can't do bundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT") on this bundle because it does not have this key. I noticed that in the google doc it says that getBuyIntentExtraParams is a variant of getBuyIntent so I am assuming that getBuyIntentExtraParams should return a BUY_INTENT key.

So I am wondering what should I do to properly use this method? I noticed that there is an issue with google about the documentation: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37140925

Here is my code:

ArrayList skus = new ArrayList();

skus.add("product.id.name.tier1");

Bundle extraBundle = new Bundle();

extraBundle.putStringArrayList("skusToReplace", skus);

getBuyIntentExtraParams(7, "app.package.name", "subs" , "product.id.name.tier2", DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD, extraBundle);

Notice how the 3rd argument "subs" should be where the 4th argument "product.id.name.tier2" is and vice versa according to the doc. But when I do that it complains and says it does not know what item type is product.id.name.tier2. So I think the doc is not right.

PS: I also tried to put 6 instead of 7 (api version) no luck

I guess my main question is how do I use GetBuyIntentExtraParams differently than getBuyIntent?

I am using sdk min and target 19 btw.

I also noticed that I don't see this in my InAppBillingService.aidl file
isBillingSupportedExtraParams.

UPDATE:

I added this into my InAppBillingService.aidl file:

Bundle getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus(int apiVersion, String packageName,
in List oldSkus, String newSku, String type, String developerPayload);

Then I called that instead of getBuyIntentExtraParams and it worked!

I am just wondering is this the right method to call?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question on how to use getBuyIntentExtraParams, I found out that you need to copy the actual aidl file from google and replace your aidl file.. Do not copy the code inside google's aidl and replace your code.

Latest aidl file from google: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/0154723d8c97011fb5ce0163d55b496cb5ebccb7/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus is the right method to use for upgrading and downgrading subscriptions.